# Are there any infinite-dimesional division algebras over the real numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, division-algebras

I have read that the only finite-dimesional division algebras over the real numbers have dimensions 1, 2, 4, and 8. Are there any infinite-dimensional division algebras over the real numbers?

Comment: Yes, take the field of rational functions. This works over any field.

Comment: How exactly do rational functions form an algebra over the real numbers?

Comment: To be clear, I mean the field $\mathbb{R}(t)$, the fraction field of the ring $\mathbb{R}[t]$ of polynomials in one variable over $\mathbb{R}$. The $\mathbb{R}$-algebra structure comes from the inclusion of constant functions. Again, this works with $\mathbb{R}$ replaced by any field.